# Finding the shared library name to use with dlload

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, lazy-loading, autoconf, system-calls

In my open-source project [Artha](http://artha.sourceforge.net/) I use [libnotify](http://developer-next.gnome.org/libnotify/) for showing passive desktop notifications to the user.

Instead of statically linking libnotify, a lookup at runtime is made for the shared object (.so) file via `dlload`, if available on the target machine, Artha exposes the notification feature in it's GUI. On app. start, a call to `dlload` with filename param as `libnotify.so.1` is made and if it returns a non-null pointer, then the feature is exposed.

A recurring problem with this model is that every time the version number of the library is bumped, Artha's code needs to be updated, currently `libnotify.so.4` is the latest to entail such an occurance.

Is there a linux system call (irrespective of the distro the app. is running on), which can tell me if a particular library's shared object is available at runtime? I know that there exists the bruteforce option of enumerating the library by going from 1 to say 10, I find the solution ugly and inelegant.

Also, if this can be addressed via [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html), then that solution is welcome too I.e. at build time, based on the target machine, the configure.h generated should've the right .so name that can be passed to `dlload`.

**P.S.:** I think good distros follow the style of creating links to `libnotify.so.x` so that a programmer can just do `dlload("libnotify.so", RTLD_LAZY)` and the right version numbered .so is loaded; unfortunately not all distros follow this, including Ubuntu.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827181/dynamic-loading-of-shared-objects-using-dlopen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: you don't.

`dlopen()` is not designed to deal with things like that, and trying to load whichever soversion you find on the system just because it happens to have the symbols you need is not a good way to do it.

Different sonames have different ABIs, and different ABIs means that you may be calling the same exact symbol name that is expecting a different set (or different size) of parameters, which will cause crashes or misbehaviour that are extremely difficult do debug.

You should have a read on [how shared object versions work](https://blog.flameeyes.eu/2009/04/shared-object-version) and [what an ABI is](https://blog.flameeyes.eu/2009/04/application-binary-interface).

The `libfoo.so` link is there for the link editor (`ld`) and is usually installed with the `-devel` packages for that reason; it might also very well not be a link but rather a text file with a linker script, often times on purpose to avoid exactly what you're trying to do.