# Loading Linux libraries at runtime

Tags: linux, ld, elf, dlopen, shared-libraries

I think a major design flaw in Linux is the shared object hell when it comes to distributing programs in binary instead of source code form.

Here is my specific problem: I want to publish a Linux program in ELF binary form that should run on as many distributions as possible so my mandatory dependencies are as low as it gets: The only libraries required under any circumstances are libpthread, libX11, librt and libm (and glibc of course). I'm linking dynamically against these libraries when I build my program using gcc.

Optionally, however, my program should also support ALSA (sound interface), the Xcursor, Xfixes, and Xxf86vm extensions as well as GTK. But these should only be used if they are available on the user's system, otherwise my program should still run but with limited functionality. For example, if GTK isn't there, my program will fall back to terminal mode. Because my program should still be able to run without ALSA, Xcursor, Xfixes, etc. I cannot link dynamically against these libraries because then the program won't start at all if one of the libraries isn't there.

So I need to manually check if the libraries are present and then open them one by one using dlopen() and import the necessary function symbols using dlsym(). This, however, leads to all kinds of problems:

**1) Library naming conventions:**
Shared objects often aren't simply called "libXcursor.so" but have some kind of version extension like "libXcursor.so.1" or even really funny things like "libXcursor.so.0.2000". These extensions seem to differ from system to system. So which one should I choose when calling dlopen()? Using a hardcoded name here seems like a very bad idea because the names differ from system to system. So the only workaround that comes to my mind is to scan the whole library path and look for filenames starting with a "libXcursor.so" prefix and then do some custom version matching. But how do I know that they are really compatible?

**2) Library search paths:** Where should I look for the *.so files after all? This is also different from system to system. There are some default paths like /usr/lib and /lib but *.so files could also be in lots of other paths. So I'd have to open /etc/ld.so.conf and parse this to find out all library search paths. That's not a trivial thing to do because /etc/ld.so.conf files can also use some kind of *include* directive which means that I have to parse even more .conf files, do some checks against possible infinite loops caused by circular *include* directives etc. Is there really no easier way to find out the search paths for *.so?

So, my actual question is this: Isn't there a more convenient, less hackish way of achieving what I want to do? Is it really so complicated to create a Linux program that has some optional dependencies like ALSA, GTK, libXcursor... but should also work without it! Is there some kind of standard for doing what I want to do? Or am I doomed to do it the hackish way?

Thanks for your comments/solutions!

Comment: Have you considered building your own shared libraries? These could be dynamically linked with the system libraries you require, be where you expect them to be and will have names known to you.

Comment: Also, you might want to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827181/dynamic-loading-of-shared-objects-using-dlopen?rq=1

Comment: @1: Right, this might be a workaround but then I'd have to distribute my app with accompanying *.so files. I'd prefer to have just a single ELF binary in my distribution.

Comment: You might make your application free software (GPLv3), and leave the burden of packaging it to distributions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think a major design flaw in Linux is the shared object hell when it comes to distributing programs in binary instead of source code form.

This isn't a design flaw as far as creators of the system are concerned; it's an advantage -- it encourages you to distribute programs in source form. Oh, you wanted to sell your software? Sorry, that's not the use case Linux is optimized for.

> Library naming conventions: Shared objects often aren't simply called "libXcursor.so" but have some kind of version extension like "libXcursor.so.1" or even really funny things like "libXcursor.so.0.2000".

Yes, this is called external library versioning. Read about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-0690/chapter5-5/index.html). As should be clear from that description, if you compiled your binaries using headers on a system that would normally give you `libXcursor.so.1` as a runtime reference, then the *only* shared library you are compatible with is `libXcursor.so.1`, and trying to `dlopen` `libXcursor.so.0.2000` will lead to unpredictable crashes.

Any system that provides `libXcursor.so` but not `libXcursor.so.1` is either a broken installation, or is also incompatible with your binaries.

> Library search paths: Where should I look for the *.so files after all?

You *shouldn't* be trying to dlopen any of these libraries using their full path. Just call `dlopen("libXcursor.so.1", RTLD_GLOBAL);`, and the runtime loader will search for the library in *system-appropriate* locations.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I have it working now using the SONAME of the shared object with dlopen().